# Accessing a leafletjs object throughout webpage

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Having spent several hours looking through the docs, searching on here and looking at the "L" Object returned, I'm at a loss how to reference my leafletjs map for modifications, adding layers, markers, etc, throughout my code.

I get how the initial reference is destroyed to conserve memory, but how is it possible for me to reference my leaflet map and add/remove markers, layers, set styles, fit to bounds, etc after it's been created.

```
    var layers=[];

var leafletMap = new L.map('mmp', { zoomControl: false, preferCanvas: true }).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18, attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy;<a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
}).addTo(leafletMap);

var myGeojSonLayerGroup = L.geoJson(worldCountries.features, {
    onEachFeature: myOnEachFeature,
    style: myStyle
}).addTo(leafletMap)


function myOnEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var props = feature.properties;
    var ni = {}
    ni.name = props.name;
    ni.layer = layer
    leafletLayers.push(ni);
}
$('#mmp').data('layers',layers)
```

Using the above I can indeed colour various countries later on in my code, but I can't call leafletMap.fitBounds because leafletmap is no longer available, even though this was created as a global variable.

Is there any possible solution to this?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood the question but you can check an example here of me referencing the map after creation through a function that adds a marker: https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/vJmgEa

Comment: Yeah, that works perfectly, so I guess the problem is something I'm doing wrong somewhere.  If I console.log(leafletMap) outside of the function I just get nothing, so really confused.

Comment: There is missing code in the example you provided so I can't tell what the problem is exactly. But I tried it without the "geojsonlayergroup" and until the "$" line I still had reference to the map in chrome debugger.

Comment: Yeah have managed to get it 'kinda' working if I create the map outside of a function.  Creating it inside a function called "CreateMap()" even though there's a global variable, seems to destroy everything.  Very weird, but thank you for your example, it did 100% prove that it's doable.

Comment: Great happy to help :)

Comment: Your question looks similar to this one, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412056/find-leaflet-map-object-after-initialisation/45416887#45416887

Comment: Yep, very very similar indeed, glad it wasn't just me that had a problem.  Thanks for pointing towards this