# Call map.setView for javascript from a function with variables

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet

I am running a django app with tables2. I then set up a field with linkify where i want to zoom to a feature by running a javascript function.
My code in the renderd htm is:

```
<div id="map" class="leaflet-container-default"></div>
    ......
<td ><a href="javascript:onclick=myFunction(7.22591038,61.1982749)">Zoom til</a></td>....

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(lat,long) {
map.setView([lat,long], 15);
}
</script>
```

Django laflet generatet map script where the map is defined:

```
<script>
(function () {

    function loadmap() {
        var djoptions = {"srid": null, "extent": [[-90, -180], [90, 180]], "fitextent": true, "center": [61.2340642364768, 7.10221073722647], "zoom": 12 },
            options = {djoptions: djoptions, initfunc: loadmap,
                       globals: false, callback: window.map_init},
            map = L.Map.djangoMap('map', options);
        
    }
    var loadevents = ["load"];
    if (loadevents.length === 0) loadmap();
    else if (window.addEventListener) for (var i=0; i<loadevents.length; i++) window.addEventListener(loadevents[i], loadmap, false);
    else if (window.jQuery) jQuery(window).on(loadevents.join(' '), loadmap);
    
})();
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It dosent work. The console returns that map is not a function

Comment: Have you defined the map variable? Like: `var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);`

Comment: the leaflet django app generate this map script like added in post

Answer (score 0):

The `map` variable shown in the code snippet is internal to the inner scope of the `loadmap` function. Therefore you can no longer access it later on.

There is probably a way to retrieve it through Django Leaflet API.

Otherwise, if you can have a script executed before Django Leaflet one, you can setup a Leaflet init hook ehich can provide you with the map reference. See [Find Leaflet map object after initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412056/find-leaflet-map-object-after-initialisation/45435508?r=SearchResults#45435508)

Comment: Thx, the easy way was to set up a hook :-)